# Google Play Console не удается подтвердить личность

Tags: google-play-console

Я начинающий андройд разработчик. Столкнулся с проблемой подтверждения личности через гугл консоль.

Вообщем, у меня два аккаунта гугл -- один публичный, а второй -- приватный. Приватный был выбран в качестве аккаунта разработчика. Этот аккаунт изначально создавался с регионом США, поэтому гугл требует подтверждение Американским Id: паспорт, гринкарта, или водительские. Первый раз я им прислал российский паспорт в качестве подтверждения, и пришел отказ. В отказе написано, что мы не можем убедиться что вас зовут так, как вы указали, а также, ваше место проживание вызывает сомнение. Стоит отметить, что я действительно не проживаю в США. Я решил поменять место жительство в настройках аккаунта, однако, Google Console не видит эти изменения и продолжает рекомендовать подтверждение через Американский Id.

Вообщем, начитался страшилок, теперь боюсь, что мой аккаунт могут заблокировать за "странную активность" плюс вранье, это так? И что делать, если не могу подтвердить свое место проживания? В случае чего, могу ли вернуть 25 долларов за создание аккаунта разработчика? Отправил снова на подтверждение, если придет отказ, какие мои следующие шаги?

Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: В вашем паспорте написание имени на английском языке? Если нет, то попробуйте им отправить водительское удостоверение.

Comment: Я отправлял загранпаспорт, то есть да. Единственный момент, во время отправки Гугл ругался на фото, якобы оно криво обрезалось, но и посмотреть не дает тоже.
Насчёт водительского, там же на русском написано.

Comment: в водительском фио дублируются также на англ.

Comment: Да, действительно так, сейчас глянул. Пока вторая попытка еще не вернулась, ожидаю.

Comment: Ну что ж пришел снова отказ. Пишет, не удалось подтвердить личность по причинам:
-не удалось проверить документ
-документы из этой страны не принимаются для подтверждения. 
Круто, что дальше?

Comment: С водительскими стало получше. Сократился на 1 пункт требования по доказательству личности. Теперь висит вот что : "Документы (Официальное удостоверение личности с фотографией) из этой страны не принимаются для подтверждения." Походу нужно новый акк создавать :(

Comment: @Artemast получилось решить последний пункт?

Comment: @Rinat привет, да удалось. Просто написал в поддержку, объяснил ситуацию, сказал, что этот аккаунт был создан под США, тк когда то жил там, и нужен был местный акк. В общем месяц возвращал гроши, по итогу вернул. Создал абсолютно чистый аккаунт. Указал тру информацию о нём, в том числе, ФИО, др и страну проживания. Страну проживания нужно указывать, согласно тому, гражданином какой страны ты являешься. Например, живешь в Казахстане, но по паспорту РФ, указываешь РФ! И второй пункт, страна оплаты $25, должна соответствовать пункту ранее. То есть должно быть РФ-РФ или Казахстан-Казахстан!

Comment: @Rinat, нельзя писать РФ-Казахстан или Канада-РФ, такого быть не должно. Гражданство страны, должно совпадать с адресом оплаты комиссии! Важный момент. И лучше всего подтверждать водительскими.

Answer (score 0):

Как бы банально не было, напиши в поддержку гугл они должны тебе помочь.
Если это баг в сервесе то они должны его решить.

Comment: ну попробую....